# PostgreSql: Script for create table with 1000 of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need create table with 1000 of columns and 1M of rows with random data.

I know script for INSERT 1M of rows in table with some column:

```
INSERT INTO foo
   SELECT md5(random()::text), md5(random()::text), ..., md5(random()::text)
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS i;
```

But I don't know:

1. How to **create** table with 1000 of colums (names: c1, c2, c3, ... , c999, c1000) by script (need the SQL script)
2. How to insert 1M of rows in the table with result of `md5(random()::text)` for each field of row (need the SQL script)
3. Is it possible to create table with 1M of colums? Or PostgeSql has limit of 1200 colums? Maybe I can change this limit?

Answer (score 0):

> How to create table with 1000 of colums (names: c1, c2, c3, ... , c999, c1000) by script (need the SQL script):

```
CREATE TABLE t AS
WITH cte AS (
  VALUES (
   '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''   
  )
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE 1=2;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0e41ffc9a8b1bab609e37068dd25aae6)**

> Is it possible to create table with 1M of colums? Or PostgeSql has limit of 1200 colums? Maybe I can change this limit?

I don't think so. Based on [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/about/)

```
Maximum Columns per Table   250 - 1600 depending on column types
```

Comment: Thank you! But 1) I was expecting a way without this huge list of (' ', ' ' ...)    2) How insert 1M rows to the table? Do you have ideas?